# Update arraycollection from itemRenderer

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a have a program like following:

```
  [Bindable]
  private var myDP:Array = [
       {label: "1", selected: true},
       {label: "2", selected: false}
   ];

  </mx:Script>

<mx:DataGrid dataProvider="{myDP}">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="label" headerText="Label" />
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="selected" itemRenderer="mx.controls.CheckBox" />
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

It works fine, but when the the checkbox is changed, the value is not updated on the arraylist. Is there a way to trigger some function when the checkbox is changed on this item renderer?

Answer (score 0):

On checkbox change event you can dispatch event like following:

```
<s:CheckBox change="onChange()" />

    private function onChange():void
    {
         var testEvent:CustomEvent = new CustomEvent(CustomEvent.SELECT_ITEM_EVENT,true);
         CustomEvent.selectedItem = data;
         dispatchEvent(selectEvent);
    }
```

And get/add EventListener that event in main page:

```
addEventListener(CustomEvent.SELECT_ITEM_EVENT, this.selectFunction);

private function selectFunction(item:CustomEvent):void
{
   // Your Action
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your code need slight modification; replace below code line

```
<mx:DataGridColumn dataField="selected" itemRenderer="mx.controls.CheckBox" />
```

with

```
<mx:DataGridColumn dataField="selected" itemRenderer="itemRenderer.checkBoxRndr" />
```

and add an item-renderer component(say 'checkBoxRndr') in the project within a folder 'itemRenderer'.

And the item -renderer will be,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <mx:HBox xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" width="100%" height="20" verticalAlign="middle" 
     verticalGap="0" horizontalGap="0" horizontalAlign="center" verticalScrollPolicy="off" horizontalScrollPolicy="off"
     paddingBottom="0" paddingLeft="0" paddingRight="0" paddingTop="0">
  <mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        override public function set data(value:Object):void{
            if(value != null){
                super.data = value;
                if(data.hasOwnProperty("selected") && data.selected != null){
                    rndrCheckBox.selected = data.selected;
                }
            }
        }
        private function onChange():void{
            data.selected = rndrCheckBox.selected;
        }

    ]]>
 </mx:Script>
 <mx:CheckBox id="rndrCheckBox" change="{onChange()}"/>
</mx:HBox>
```